# Как аллоцировать память в куче при разработке модуля ядра linux 5.x?

Tags: linux, c, ядро

Как аллоцировать память в куче при разработке модуля ядра `linux 5.x`?

Я хотел использовать `kmalloc`, но в ядре 5.17 отсутствует заголовок `linux/stab.h`

Comment: Гугл подсказвает, что хедер называется `slab`, не `stub`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, опечатка, все равно нет

Comment: Все еще мимо, не `stab` а `slab`. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, благодарю) похоже нужно взять перерыв